# how to highlight blank rows automatically in excel using vb script

Tags: vbscript

I want to automate an Excel sheet as if there is any blank cell then the whole row should be highlighted. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you show us [what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I suspect that you are not intending to use VBScript (as your title suggests) or vb.net (as the tag you used suggests), but vba (the language that comes with Excel). If that is the case, I suggest you edit the question to use the excel-vba tag instead of vb.net. That will bring you question to the attention of right audience.

Comment: A [conditional format](http://superuser.com/questions/362759/using-indirect-and-and-if-for-conditional-formatting) would probably be a better choice. Also, this kind of question should rather be asked on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want VBScript and not a VBA macro, I would do the following:

```
Dim xl
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\FilePath\FileName.xlsx")
xl.Workbooks.Sheets("SheetName").Activate
xl.Range("A1").End(xl.xlDown).Offset(1,0).Select
```

Then you can have the code to do something with that.